Не открывается VS Code через браузер (xdg-open) open application
При использовании различных расширений VS Code часто бывает ситуация, когда на сайте присутствует url ссылка на "vscode://abcde". Однако при нажатии на неё  всплывает окно "Open xdg-open ?" и ничего происходит. Если же выбрать "приложение, которым открыть" - code, то откроется сам VS Code, но авторизации с этого внешнего сайта не происходит.


Решение:
В vscode.desktop прописать/изменить следующие поля
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/vscode
Exec=code --open-url %U

А затем в bash выполнить команду
xdg-settings set default-url-scheme-handler vscode vscode.desktop

